# Array_push gives null in JSON file

Tags: php, json

I want to adding array's to an `existing .json` file with with a HTML form.

this is my PHP:

```
$myFile = "data.json";      
$newArray = array(
    'name'=> $_POST['name'],
    'date'=> $_POST['date']
);

$fileTmp = file_get_contents($myFile);
$tempArray = json_decode($fileTmp);
array_push($tempArray, $newArray);
$jsonData = json_encode($tempArray);
file_put_contents($myFile, $jsonData);
```

this is my JSON:

```
[
  {
    "name": "name 1",
    "date": "01.02.2017"
  },
  {
    "name": "name 2",
    "date": "05.02.2017"
  },
  {
    "name": "name 3",
    "date": "05.03.2017"
  }
]
```

The problem is i got the warning

> "array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in..."

and in the JSON there's is only null. What is my problem with my code?

Comment: `$tempArray = json_decode($fileTmp,true);
array_push($tempArray, $newArray);`  try it and tell

Comment: Does the error happen also with the provided json file or only when starting with an empty one?

Comment: @Anant oh yes, thank you! didnt seen that... 
aghidini problem solved but it was with the provided json

Comment: @PatrickDully  glad to help you.:):)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a second parameter to `json_decode()` and set it to `true`:-

```
$tempArray = json_decode($fileTmp,true); 
array_push($tempArray, $newArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from using the associative version of `json_decode` as already stated in the other answer, I think that the problem is your input json file.

You should check for valid content and create your default array if the json is empty:

```
$fileTmp = file_get_contents($myFile);
$tempArray = json_decode($fileTmp, true);
if (!$tempArray) {
    $tempArray = array();
}
...
```

Comment: Actually his json what he shown  is valid, but this code is also useful to prevent from errors. so +1.

Comment: @Anant I agree that his input json is valid but I suspected that he was receiving the errors only at the beginning, that is when the input json was empty (or does not exist). I thought that `json_decode` should produce a valid array also with `false` as the second parameter, it should simply produce an array of objects, but the OP error is about the first parameter (i.e. the array).

Comment: when you will try to push an array into an array of objects you will get this error too (i think)

Comment: @Anant Actually it works (albeit the final array contains objects and the newly added array): http://codepad.org/ITdcXai5 it even produces a valid output json: http://codepad.org/V5STYCCB

Answer (score -1):

I complied code, it works. Check permissions for data.json file.